# Как правильно обращаться на "ВЫ" в интернете?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Как следует обращаться к незнакомому человеку в интернете? Обращение нужно писать с прописной буквы или со строчной? И почему?

**UPD:** Хочу закрыть вопрос, поэтому нужен хотя бы один правильный ответ. Под словом "правильный" я подразумеваю такой ответ, который отталкивается от *официальных правил русского языка*, а не от степени уважения к собеседнику или чего-то ещё в таком роде.

Comment: > Хочу закрыть вопрос, поэтому нужен хотя бы один правильный ответ.  

Ну так ответьте сами на вопрос: собственное мнение Вам уж точно понравится ;-))

Comment: @DocentI Нужно не чьё-то мнение, а точный и правильный ответ. Вопреки распространённому заблуждению, правила чётко регулируют этот вопрос, хотя их и сложно найти в интернете (нужно знать, где искать).

Если никто так и не даст правильного ответа, то со временем я, конечно же, отвечу сам. Но прежде я хочу дать возможность другим срубить баллов. Идеология данного ресурса предполагает, что нужно действовать именно так: не самому отвечать на свои вопросы, а давать возможность другим, награждая их баллами за правильные ответы.

Comment: DocentI Заметил. Но выглядело это, как шутка, совмещенная с советом, который действительно имеет смысл.

Подобная твердолобость типична для математиков. У них негибкое мышление, что обусловлено спецификой тех знаний, которые его сформировали. Я сам математик, поэтому знаю, о чём говорю. Только мне повезло, и в данном вопросе я зафиксировался на правильном варианте :)

Comment: Ну, может мой способ действий тоже правильный. Тем более, что у меня нет рассылок. Думаю, основные нестыковки - именно при написании "псевдоличных" сообщений, маскируемых большой буквой под личные.   
Но это относится не к грамматике, а скорее к психологии: это элементарная лесть.  
Не согласна считать себя "твердолобой" (не потому, что обиделась). Как раз наоборот: я признаю не только формально-грамматические правила, но еще и специфику ситуации. Если в рассылке я увижу "Вы", усмехнусь, и вспомню Крылова (Ворона и лисица).

Comment: @DocentI Что значит "тоже правильный" в данном контексте? Правила в русском языке существуют только одни. Нет другого свода положений о языке, который был бы "тоже правилами". И эти единственные правила допускают написание первой буквы на усмотрение пишущего только в одном единственном жанре - эпистолярном (личная переписка). В других жанрах (проза, интервью, публичный диалог и т.д.), проявление уважения таким образом совершенно неуместно. Кроме двух жанров (официальное письмо и анкета), где проявление именно такой степени уважения является обязательным (несмотря на личное отношение).

Comment: Естественно, правила одни! Мне ли как математику этого не знать! Я имею в виду, что мои интуитивно воспринятые правила могут совпадать с Вашими, почерпнутыми из нормативных документов.  

Кроме того я, не являясь журналистом или писателем, и не попадаю в ситуации, описанные Вами.

Comment: @DocentI Естественно, они могли бы совпадать. В теории. Но те конкретные правила, которые вы воспринимаете интуитивно в данный момент, совершенно определённо ни с чем не совпадают. Ведь ко мне вы обращаетесь с большой буквы, а это правилам противоречит. Удивительно, но в качестве примера вы привели как раз те немногие профессии, в которых люди могут позволить себе не знать правил вообще. Их ошибки исправляют корректоры. Даже если они будут писать абсолютно безграмотно, никто этого не заметит.

Comment: Я не знаю, кем являетcя г-н @shamov, но подозреваю, что он из числа тех ревнителей русского языка, которые, усвоив три правила, яростно воююет с теми, кто знает четвертое. Причем средства для этого нре выбирает.  
@DocentI, зуб даю, что "товарисч" просто не разбирается в значениях терминов ими употребляемых. Особенно поражет трактовка понятия "личное". Если, конечно, это действиетельно такая трактовка, а не ломовой троллинг.

Comment: Все равно буду писать как нравится, и как привыкла.

Comment: Тем более, что это правильно )))

Answer (score 3):

Хороший вопрос. Дело в том, что помимо общеизвестного "Вы - к одному, вы - к двум и более" есть два основных правила, регулирующих написание "Вы" при обращении к одному человеку.

1. "Вы" с заглавной всегда используется в официальном обращении.
2. "Вы" с заглавной используется только **при личном** обращении.

Всё это касается не только интернета, а вообще любой переписки. И если в отношении первого пункта наблюдаются некоторые различия мнений, то второй пункт следует соблюдать неукоснительно. Ни при каких обстоятельствах не следует писать "Вы" (с заглавной), если сообщение адресуется нескольким пользователям, даже при официальном его характере. Например, неприемлемо объявление типа "Уважаемый пользователь, Ваш аккаунт будет заблокирован", особенно при массовой рассылке. Это сообщение адресуется не личности, а "пользователю".

Вообще в интернете этот вопрос актуален в основном на форумах, реже - в чатах. На многих форумах придерживаются правила, что "вы" с заглавной стоит писать, только если в начале поста конкретный пользователь назван по нику и речь идет об официальном обращении к нему, обычно это касается связи с модератором или админом. Ну и в диалоге, если он начался после такого поста.

Мне такой подход представляется весьма и весьма разумным. Не стоит на форуме писать "Вы" во  фразе "я с вами не согласен", если обсуждается техника строительства пирамид или философия Конфуция. Впрочем, у такой идеи есть и недостатки, например, необходимость смены формы при общении на разные темы.

Ещё заметил, что на Вы иногда переходят, когда страсти начинают закипать. Но тут не могу советовать. Это хорошо, когда оба собеседника понимают и принимают такую идею.

В любом случае следует придерживаться единообразия формы обращения хотя бы в пределах одного поста.
~~~~~~

По ограничениям форума не могу более комментировать афоноризмы г-ны @Shsmov 'a, в самом диалоге, но не могу пропустить очередное вранье. Поэтому здесь.

У слова "личный" **есть** значение принадлежащий одному лицу. Таким образом и разговоры о том, что "личный" не может трактоваться как напрвленный к одному лицу. Я не понимаю, зачем надо опять тень на плетень наводить?

~~~~~~

> Что значит "без публичности"? В официальных правилах русского языка публичность служит определяющим критерием. Там чётко сказано, что одним из исключений, в которых буква должна быть прописной, является личное письмо.
> (shamov)

А то и значит, уважаемый, что противопоставление "личный" - "публичный" (даже если предположить, что в каком-то значении это действительно антонимы) здесь абсолютно неуместно. Сформулируруйте свою мысль так, чтобы эта никому не нужная и ничего не поясняющая "публичность" не мозолила глаза. Если, конечно, эта мысль у вас есть.

Я повторяю, "личное обращение" здесь означает **адресованное к одному лицу**. Одно может быть приватным или публичным, это не имеет значения.

Идея же о том, что публикация письма делает его публичным - и следовательно, якобы, требует замены "Вы" на "вы" полностью абсурдна. Ничего более идиотского, простите, не читал.

Вы так и не дали нормальную ссылку на ответ ИРА по поводу вы и Вы, который якобы читали. Неужели всё ещё надеетесь, на тезис "тут движок ссылки не пропускает"?

> Не хочется вас дополнительно расстраивать, но слово "приватный" как раз и обозначает "не общественный".
> (shamov)

Не хочется Вас расстраивать, но вам опять не удалось никого ввести в залуждение.
"Приватный" не является антонимом к "общественный", во всяком случае - полным. 
Как и ваш довод - содержательным.

Кстаи, закрыть вопрос можно не дожидаясь правильного ответа. 
Вы опять вводите народ в заблуждение.

> Не расстраивайтесь так. Когда-нибудь вы научитесь читать примечания в Вики полностью, а не прерывать чтение, увидев первую же ссылку, которая действительно давно "протухла" (всё-таки ответ был дан аж в 2000 году). Обязательно попробуйте потом поставить эту ссылку с помощью здешнего движка.
> (Shavov) 
> Мне-то чего расстраиваться? У меня-то все ссылки работают. И движок их у меня пропускает. И даже танцевать не мешает.

~~~~

ЗЫ Собственно спор давно перешел на стадию "один говорит - никто не слушает". Единственный момент, который остался за скобками - анкета, в которой предлагается писать "Вы". Я позволю себе с этиv категорически не согласться.
Думаю, что список обязвтельного "Вы" анкета пополнила по чьей-то неумной инициативе. Никаких авторитетных рекомендация на этот счет я не видел, разумных объяснений - тем более (ну кроме того, что хуже не будет), а доверять ссылкам на битые ссылкам г-на Shamov'а как-то не пристало.

Comment: В вашем ответе есть здравое зерно, но он неверен в той части, где вы говорите о личном обращении. Местоимение "вы" уже само по себе является личным, т.е. адресованным некоему лицу или лицам. Если оно присутствует, то обращение уже никак не может считаться безличным. Не имеет значения, назван адресат по имени или же по своей роли. Вторую часть правила, в которой говорится про личную переписку, следует понимать иначе. В таком контексте слово "личная" служит антонимом к слову "публичная". То есть имеется в виду переписка, не предназначенная для прочтения третьими лицами.

Comment: 1. О том и речь,что нельзя на Вы обращаться не лично. А это постоянно делают. Обращение "Вытирайте Ваши ноги" никак нельзя назвать личным.
2. Про личную-публичную вообще не понял. Я вообще говорил не о пререписке, а об обращении. Вот сейчас я с вами беседую лично, но публично (в Вашей терминологии). Слово "Вашей" я здесь написал с заглавной потому, что оно граничит с переходом на личность. В противном случае я бы скорее употребил строчную.

Comment: 3. Вы вообще спрашиваете или внедряете свой подход? В последнем случае логично было бы предупредить, что хотите поспорить, а не поличить справку. Впрочем, тут я не имею полномочий настаивать.

Comment: Что тут может быть непонятного? Слово "личный" служит антонимом сразу к двум словам - "безличный" и "публичный". Многие ошибочно полагают, что в правиле про обращение на "вы" слово используется в качестве антонима к первому. На самом же деле, там речь идёт об обращении в личной переписке, т.е. о такой переписке, которая не является публичной.

Comment: Боюсь, что кроме Вас здесь никто не полагает, что "личный" в данном контексте мождет явиться антонимом к "безличный". К публичный - тоже. Личное обращение здесь означат обращение к одному лицу. Не более. При    
Кстаи, а переписке здесь тоже никто не говорит. Кроме Вас, разумеется.
Так что здесь ещё очень много чего есть не понимать.

Comment: Очень жаль, если так. Я надеялся, что уровень грамотности здесь хотя бы чуть-чуть выше, чем в остальном интернете.

Comment: Так до Вашего появления он и был "выше, чем в остальнгом". 
Вот только не надо неприятие собсвенных заморочек объяснять неграмотностью окружающих.

Comment: Не расстраивайтесь так. Когда-нибудь вы научитесь читать примечания в Вики полностью, а не прерывать чтение, увидев первую же ссылку, которая действительно давно "протухла" (всё-таки ответ был дан аж в 2000 году). Обязательно попробуйте потом поставить эту ссылку с помощью здешнего движка.

Answer (score 3):

…Получаю перед Новым годом письмо от коллег-русистов:
«Дорогие друзья, Ассоциация Русского Языка, Культуры и Образования… сердечно поздравляет Вас с праздниками! Пусть Новый Год принесет Вам только все самое хорошее! Открылся новый онлайн ресурс для русскоязычных образовательных центров…».
Отвечаю:
«Дорогой друг! За поздравление, конечно, спасибо! И вашу организацию с Новым годом тоже! Но не пишутся в русском языке в середине предложения с большой буквы слова «русский», «язык», «культура», «образование», «журнал», «год»... Слово «Гитлер» с большой буквы пишется в русском языке в середине предложения, а слово «культура» – не пишется, вот такой парадокс! «Онлайн-ресурс» желательно написать через черточку. И уж само собою – нельзя обращаться на «вы» с большой буквы ко всем и сразу. Какие же это русский язык и русская культура, какая же это у вас русская образовательная ассоциация, если мы грамотно не умеем по-русски написать?
Уже просто чумеешь от обилия этих безграмотных «Центров Русской Культуры» и пошлой безграмотности коллег-филологов.

Comment: Ну Вы несколько палку перегибаете. "Ассоциация..." тут похожа на имя собственное. А посему надо разбираться, с какой там буквы...    
А поздравлялки вполне могут рассылать секретарши, орфографическим тонкостям не обученные...  

Забыл спросить, а что за шарашка-то? Если это очередной политпроект, цель которого единственно развести возню вокруг статуса русского языка где-нибудь на Украине или в Прибалтике, то не парьтесь.

Answer (score 2):

Я согласна с [[@Инна](/users/466/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0)](/users/466/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0), кроме разве слова "категорично". В конце концов, каждый может иметь свое мнение. Я пишу так: к одному человеку - Вы, к нескольким - вы. Простенько и со вкусом.

> Не стоит на форуме писать "Вы" во фразе "я с вами не согласен", если обсуждается техника строительства пирамид или философия Конфуция.

Замысловато! И слишком сложно.

И почему же нельзя написать "Вы" в рассылке для пользователей? Ведь обращение идет к каждому индивидуально.
Пожалуй, своим студентам (иногда пишу им e-mailы) написала бы так:
 - К 20.11 вы должны представить рефераты по теме ...
 - В Вашем реферате недостаточно раскрыто ...

Comment: Если в первом случае вы делаете массовую рассылку по всем студентам, а во втором - пишете личный e-mail, то это абсолютно правильно. Хотя вы и руководствуетесь несуществующим правилом. Настоящее правило, которое есть в словарях, подразумевает, что нужно всегда писать со строчной буквы, кроме трёх оговоренных исключений. Два из них предписывают писать с прописной, а третье допускает оба варианта в зависимости от степени уважения.

Comment: Опять исключения! Сложно это... Лучше буду обрашать внимание только на количество адресатов.

Comment: Да уж... Похоже, это уже к другому вопросу ближе. Про троллинг. 
Как один из видов оного. Юзер регулярно выдает псевдонаучный текст - и решительно не собирается отвечать на вопросы по сути его афонаризмов. 
Кто-нить видел, чтобы _**в словарях**_ формулировали правила?

Comment: >И почему же нельзя написать "Вы" в рассылке для пользователей? Ведь обращение идет к каждому индивидуально.  

Потому, что это нарушает принцип личного обращения. Личное - это "не каждый". Это один, конкретный. Личное обращение то, что может начинаться с "Уважаемый Имярек Батькович!" 

Я

Comment: Я говорил, что у такого подхода есть некие сложности, но я неоднократно убеждался, что он правилен по сути. Используя заглавную автор выказывает уважение к личности адресата. Грубо говоря, "Вы" это то, что выделяет контретного человека из толпы (ну и плюс некоторый официоз самого послания требуется). А получается, что это как раз к толпе предлагается обращаться на "Вы" по любому поводу.

Comment: @Docentl Если вы будете обращать внимание только на количество адресатов, то будете очень часто писать неправильно. Вспомогательное правило про количество адресатов работает только в одну сторону: когда адресатов много, то точно со строчной буквы. Предполагаю, что именно так оно и возникло. Люди просто забыли о том, что это вспомогательное одностороннее правило, и начали использовать его в обе стороны, высосав из пальца его недостающую половину (когда адресат один, писать с прописной).

Comment: Ну и пусть неправильно! Мне уже можно, я почти на пенсии... ;-))

Comment: Да всё у вас правильно. @Shamov носится с мыслью о том, что "личный" - это "не публичный", а она - по крайней мере в данном контексте - не имеет под собой ничего вразумительного. Личный это "не общественный", публичный - "не приватный".  И из-за этого _**личного**_ недоразумения такую теорию раздуть. Если, конечно, это недоразумение, а не сознательный троллинг, в чем *лично* я уже крепко сомневаюсь. 

Я ответил в своём ответе, извините за дурной каламбур.

Comment: Не хочется вас дополнительно расстраивать, но слово "приватный" как раз и обозначает "не общественный".

Comment: > Я ответил в своём ответе, извините за дурной каламбур.  

Ничего, каламбур хороший. Только пора эту вакханалию закрывать. Я "у себя" в Математике закрыла одного назойливого ферматиста, даже 2 раза. Вроде больше не вылезает.

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю, что обращаться к незнакомому человеку в письменной форме следует обращаться так, как того требуют давно установленные правила: с прописной буквы. Даже если это не уважаемый тобой человек. И неважно, в Интернете это или нет. И если кто-то скажет, что допустимо что-то другое, я категорически не соглашусь!

Comment: А я категорически не соглашусь с Вашей категорияностью. )))
Никто никогда не устанавливал таких правил общения. Тем более - в интеренте.  
И дело не в неуважении к собеседнику, а в логичности и внутреннем этикете конкретного форума.

Comment: Инна слишком категорична. Но тому могут быть причиной и личные привычки. У меня,  например,написание "вы" прочно ассоциируется с множественным числом. Поэтому, обращаясь, к одному человеку, пишу с большой буквы. (Если не потороплюсь...)

Comment: До определенного сосента я тоже свято следовал этому правилу. Если не торопился. :)
Но засилие напутсвий в метро "еам важно Ваше мнение" или в гостиницах "Уважаемый посетитель! В нашем Вы должны спать под одеялом, а не залезать внуть пододеяльника" заставили меня крепко усомниться... Ответ я нашел у классиков. В большинстве случае "вы" при передаче разговорной речи пишется со строчной... А форумы - та же разговорная речь, только га новом техническом уровне.

Comment: Дело не в том, что речь разговорная. Написание зависит от того, является текст личным или публичным. Обратимся к тем же классикам. Представьте себе письмо Пушкина к Гончаровой, опубликованное в сборнике его писем. Там есть как фотография оригинала письма, так и печатный текст. Так вот в оригинале Пушкин обращается к Гончаровой на "Вы", потому что писал ей личное письмо. А вот в печатном варианте того же самого текста обращение уже на "вы", потому что публикация письма лишает его статуса личного.

Comment: Дело в том, что Ваша идея про личность и публичтно "от и до" - плод Вашей личной фантазии. Трактовка абсурдна уже потому, что ни о каких противопоставлениях личного и публичного здесь не идет. Можно обращаться на Вы и в публичных тестах, а можно (и нужно) и на "вы" в текстах, публичными не явялются. 
Про Пушкина - никогда ничего подобного не слышал. Думаю, очередная Ваша фантазия.

Comment: Публичный тест попадает под другое исключение. Его можно считать анкетой.

Comment: А можно без "публичности" объясниться? Тем более что никто, судя по всему, не расположен принимать какие-то невразумительные толькования побобных терминов.

Comment: Что значит "без публичности"? В официальных правилах русского языка публичность служит определяющим критерием. Там чётко сказано, что одним из исключений, когда буква должна быть прописной, является личное письмо.

Comment: Может, все-таки "личное" означает - направленное конкретному человеку, а не группе? И дело не в том, сколько человек увидят это послание?  

Если же я обращаюсь на Вы к "пользователю", я хочу подчеркнуть, что мое письмо направлено лично ему. Хотя точно также оно предназначено "лично" другим. Конечно, в этом есть некий обман. Но он связан с выказанным уважением, так что простителен.

Comment: Такого значения, как направленность строго к одному лицу, у слова "личное" вообще нет. Есть так называемые личные местоимения ("вы" - одно из них), но они так называются потому, что заменяют собой лицо или лица. Множественное число не делает их менее личными в том смысле, в котором они являются заместителями лиц.

Answer (score 0):

1)не употреблять нецензурные слова.
2)со взрослыми людьми обращаться на вы.
3)если ваше фото оскорбили,не стоит
4)обращать на это внимание.
5)если вы пишете письмо уважаемому человеку,писать надо начинать с прописной буквой.*))

Comment: Это не ответ на вопрос

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://rus.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score -1):

Не читал ответы, расположенные выше. Хочу просто сказать, что нужно писать с прописной буквы.