# Снова небольшая ошибка в интерфейсе форума.

Tags: орфография

[image]

При подтверждении своего Email-адреса наткнулся на такое сообщение в интерфейсе.

Мне кажется недопустимым писать притяжательное местоимение *Ваш* в вежливом значении со строчной буквы. А Вы как считаете? У Розенталя - я случайно увидел - есть правила, которое гласит "местоимения Вы и производные от него пишутся с прописной буквы".

Что скажете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите письмо Розенталя о написании Вы/вы: http://1ynx.ru/post/5956

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых; тут ошибкой было бы написание с заглавной буквы, так как тут идёт обращение к неопределённому кругу лиц. Вопрос о "Вы-вы" неоднократно поднимался на форуме [1](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8566/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5), [2](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8717/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5-%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B?), [3](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/83/%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9?), [4](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34453/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F).

> Местоимения Вы, Ваш пишутся с прописной буквы при обращении к одному лицу в текстах следующих жанров:
>   а) *личное письмо (адресат – одно лицо)*;
>   б) *официальные документы, адресованные одному лицу*;
>   в) *анкеты, рекламные листовки (текст, адресованный неконкретному лицу)*.
>   При обращении к нескольким лицам или неопределенному кругу лиц (например, при обращении к читательской аудитории газеты или журнала, при обращении к посетителям сайта, в объявлении, адресованном широкому кругу лиц, и т. п.) местоимения вы, ваш пишутся со строчной буквы: *Дорогие подписчики! Напоминаем вам, что...; На портале «Грамота.ру» опубликован новый интерактивный диктант. Проверьте вашу грамотность!*

[Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_88)

А во-вторых; Об ошибках в интерфейсе следует сообщать не на этом форуме, а на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/), чтобы администрация их могла исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Тагир, решили Граммар -наци стать? )))

Comment: Не буду против, да.

Comment: Тогда вам на Одноклассники. Там  на форумах пишут, в большинстве случаев,  - мама не горюй!!!